# after unchecking the checkbox and updating it they are still coming checked.This is the following code

Tags: jquery

```
$("#ulWizardTeamMembersList").find('#chk' + ContactInfo[0]).attr("checked", "checked");
countChecked('ulWizardTeamMembersList', 'TeamMembers');

$("#ulWizardContactsList").find('#chk' + ContactInfo[0]).attr("checked", "checked");
countChecked('ulWizardContactsList', 'Contacts');
```

Comment: why don't you add more description..?

Comment: what are the code inside countChecked..?

Comment: these are the code for Team members list and contacts lists of two popups of team members and contacts in which team members and contacts are listed respectively. This whole code is in a  function called open edit wizard and i have to update the team members list and contact list after editing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
whatever.prop('checked', true);
```

There's a subtle difference between "properties" and "attributes," and recent versions of jQuery have started enforcing it.

See here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

And here: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Hope that helps!